# Verifying existence of constants in the common proof that an orthonormal list of vectors is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have read from many sources the well-known result that an orthonormal list of vectors $v_1,\ldots, v_m$ is linearly independent. The most common procedure is to first assume that there exist scalars $a_1,\ldots, a_m$ such that $a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_mv_m = 0$.

I'm probably overlooking something basic, but can someone explain how the existence of such a set of scalars is guaranteed?

Comment: It's not, indeed the whole point is to show that there is no such set $\{a_i\}$.  The logic here is:  to show that the set is independent, first assume that it is indeed dependent, and then derive a contradiction.

Comment: @lulu I should add that most proofs do not take the route you suggest and use the above assumption about the $a_i$ to conclude that they are all identically zero, thus proving linear independence (see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/orthonormal-set-of-vector), for example). My confusion lies in the fact that such a proof relies on the assumption that such a set of scalars does indeed exist.

Comment: But there is obviously such a set, namely all $0's$.  If you argue along the lines you suggest, you are then trying to show that that is the only example.  No problem doing it that way, of course.  The arguments are nearly equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of linear independence says that $v_1, \dots, v_m$ are linearly independent if for any $c_1, \dots, c_m \in \mathbb{F}$,
$$c_1v_1 + \dots + c_mv_m = 0 \implies c_1 = \dots = c_m = 0.$$
So one way to prove linear independence is to assume $c_1v_1 + \dots + c_mv_m = 0$ and then show that $c_1 = \dots = c_m = 0$.